# typescript не конвертирует number в string

Tags: typescript

```
const x:any = 5;
foo(x);

...

 function foo( p: string) {
    console.log('foo',p, typeof(p))
}
```

**Консоль**: foo 5  number

**Ожидалось**: foo '5' string или ошибка.

Почему нет автоматической конвертации или хотя бы ошибки? Что с этим делать?

Спасибо!

PS: Я попробовал [онлайн компилятор](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=10&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/AQMwrgdgxgLglgewqBCAUwAOAuYBnGAJzggHMBKYAbwChh7gok8EAbAUwDpWFS0ByEKn4AaTCOAwAnpnYIQaTOXI0AvjRpMIBYAA9cAQwhTgAXmABWYAG4aQ9LvK2NNIA) и получил ошибку компиляции, поэтому подправил, потому что я получаю х из json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript не конвертирует типы. TypeScript лишь проверяет соответствие типов на этапе компиляции. Но вы указали что x имеет тип any и это указывает компилятору что вы не хотите проверять тип х.

Конвертируйте типы явно:

```
const x:any = 5;
foo(x);

...

 function foo( p: any) {
    p = String(p);
    console.log('foo',p, typeof(p))
}
```

Comment: Исправил параметр функции

Comment: Жутко и не удобно, но что поделать....